# UIImage does not download URLs, even though it recognizes the correct amount it should download

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring, nsarray

I'm having a weird string / array problem. When I count the # of objects in the array (values taken using [string description], it returns two, the correct amount of objects. When I try and download the image, it the UIImage does not display anything.

Here's the log of the URLs, from the array photoArg (if you try and go them it will say they are invalid, as I changed a few lines)

```
    (
    "\n\"https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/s720x720/196148_2542310658202194_959795763_n.jpg\"",
    "\n\"https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s720x720/576808_2239914766108450_770925407_n.jpg\"\n"
     )
```

Here's my numberOfItemsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.photoArg count];
}
```

My cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (TBCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CollectionViewCell";

    TBCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *ImageURL = [self.photoArg objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

    return cell;
}
```

My TBCollectionViewCell is just a standard UICollectionViewCell, except with a UIImageView inside of it.

I'm thinking that the reason the URLs will not download in the cellForItemAtIndexPath: method is that they are not formatted properly. if that is the case, than how should I properly format the array data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your strings aren't valid URL's. You'll want to strip out the `\n\"` and the `\"` in order for dataWithContentsOfURL: do receive valid data.

```
"\n\"https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/s720x720/196148_2542310658202194_959795763_n.jpg\"",
```

It isn't really pretty, but this should work just find for you.

```
NSString *string = @"\n\"https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/s720x720/196148_2542310658202194_959795763_n.jpg\"";
NSString *noNewLines = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSString *noEscapes = [noNewLines stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

NSURL *validURL = [NSURL URLWithString:noEscapes];
```